# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError : Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I was doing an exercise and not that expert at JS, and used I `Axios`as part of the topic and tried to do MVC pattern on JS. I'm stuck with this error for hours now.

I tried to surround it with `try/catch` but won't work.

**For numerous times It was ok, I can fetch results from the server.** But now I can't. It also work at pagination part to get results from this server - [Food2Fork API](https://www.food2fork.com/).

**`SearchView.js`**

`For pagination`

```
export const renderResults = (recipes, page = 1, resultPerPage = 10) => {

//we start at 0 , 
const start = (page - 1) * resultPerPage; // 0 - 1 = 1 * 10 = 10

//end
const end = page * resultPerPage;

    //params of slice (start , end )
    recipes.slice(start, end).forEach(renderRecipe);

    //Render the btn to the page
    renderButtons(page, recipes.length, resultPerPage); }
```

From my model **`Search.js`**

```
export default class Search {

//Constructor
constructor(query){
    this.query = query;
}

//async method
async getResultFood() {

    try{
        const resultRequest = await axios(proxy+searchURL+keyAPI+`&q=${this.query}`);
        this.result = resultRequest.data.recipes;

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
} }
```

From my controller **`index.js`**

```
const controlSearch = async () => {
//1 get the search query from the view - html form
const query = SearchView.getFormTextSearch(); //from SearchView.js
console.log(query);

if(query) {
    //2 new search object and add to state
    state.search = new Search(query);

    //3 prepare the UI for results
    SearchView.clearSearchField();
    SearchView.clearSearchResults();
        //Call loader to the container
        renderLoader(variables.resultContainer);  

    //4 Search for recipes
    try{
        await state.search.getResultFood();

        //5 Render results - the `result` is the name of var
        //console.log(state.search.result)
        SearchView.renderResults(state.search.result);
            //Dismiss the loader
            dismissLoader();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
} }
```

What did I missed?

EDIT:

1. const resultRequest = await axios(proxy+searchURL+keyAPI+`&q=${this.query}`);
   `Log Result:`

[image: log result]

2. this.result = resultRequest.data.recipes;

`Log Result:`undefined

Comment: Please do a `console.log` of the `resultRequest`. Also what does the `console.log(state.search.result)` output?

Comment: from my model, its now `undefined`.

Comment: If your server returns a response that you didn't expect, either the request or the server code is broken (or just your expectation).

Comment: @Bergi - what does `data: limit` from the return Object from request? Does it mean I already limit accessing the their service?

Comment: You have to ask their API docs, not me. But yes, looks likely. And [it's a horrible practice to send errors with a 200 http status](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2018/08/24/http-headers-ftw/).